# Stuck on asking for input (C program)

Tags: c

so, I ran into this problem when i was trying to make a program that checks if the entered number is an Armstrong number and it seems easy and ok, but when I tried to execute the following code the output is not shown and i'm just just stuck with the program asking for input even though I already entered it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, a, b, c, d, e, n, remainder, result;
    printf("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b = a;
    e = a;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        a = a % 10;
        n++;
    }

    while (b != 0)
    {
        remainder = b % 10;
        result += pow(remainder, n);
        b /= 10;
    }
     if (result == e)
     {
         printf("%d is an Armstrong number.", e);
     }
     else
     {
         printf("%d isn't an Armstrong number.", e);
     }
}
```

The program  is supposed to return "number" is an Armstrong number, if the user entered an Armstrong number, and "number" isn't an Armstrong number if the user didn't enter an Armstrong number,

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger and see exactly what the program is doing and where it is "stuck". [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also, what is the exact input? If you input a non-number the `scanf` will fail and `a` will have a garbage value. Should always check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: check the exit conditions on your loops

Comment: What will `a = a % 10` be when `a` is 3? And what will it be the *next* time you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop will never exit if you enter a number where the last digit is anything but zero (0). I think you meant for it to be:

```
while (a != 0)
{
    a /= 10;
    n++;
}
```

Also, `scanf` is hardier if you allow (and discard) whitespace, as in `int cnt = scanf(" %d ", &a);` You should also check the return value from `scanf` to make sure a value was actually read.

Comment: I strongly advise against using `scanf(" %d ", &a);`, as that will continue waiting for input until the user enters a non-whitespace character and presses ENTER again. Due to this, using that `scanf` line will normally only return when the user has pressed ENTER twice. A better way to solve the problem of `scanf` leaving leftover whitespace would be to not use `scanf` at all, but to use `fgets` instead, as that function always reads exactly one line.  See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)